# Qemu Files not deleting "No Such File Or Directory Found"

Tags: terminal, malware, macos

I have some malware that installed crypto mining on my mac - I'm trying to delete all the files in terminal but keep coming up with "No Such File Or Directory Found" as an error. I'm tearing my hair out with this and its running my CPU constantly at 100%.

I've looked at other similar situations but this feels quite specific to me, Any help would be so much appreciated.

Comment: What files what commands are you running?